# Django - FileField upload_to with filename from other field's primary key

Tags: django, django-models

I have a Django model:

```
class ObservationMedia(models.Model):
    observation = models.ForeignKey(Observation)  
    audio_file = AudioFileField   ( upload_to=audio_dir, blank=True, null=True )
    photo_file = models.ImageField( upload_to=img_dir,   blank=True, null=True )
```

Where this table for media is linked to the table (Observation) the media is related to.

How can I save the `AudioFileField` (just a superclass of `FileField`) and `ImageField` so that the name of the files are the primary key of the observation, e.g. `2465.jpg`? I'm only allowed to pass 'instance' and 'filename' to `upload_to`, as far as I know, so I don't know how to pass this extra parameter.

Comment: I prefer not to store the files according to `pk` this will lead to security issue as any one then can browse through files just by incrementing the `pk`. Use some secure hash instead, which is hard to guess.

Comment: Ok, that's a good suggestion. At the moment I'm saving them with a timestamp, so that's probably better than a pk.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the pk from the instance. Like this:

```
def get_audio_path(instance, filename):
   return os.path.join(audio_dir+instance.observation.pk+".jpg")

class ObservationMedia(models.Model):
   observation = models.ForeignKey(Observation)  
   audio_file = AudioFileField   ( upload_to=get_audio_path, blank=True, null=True )
```

Comment: Oh I see, I didn't realise that `instance` was the instance of the model. However, the docs say: "In most cases, this object will not have been saved to the database yet, so if it uses the default AutoField, it might not yet have a value for its primary key field." (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#filefield). So it might not be safe.

Comment: Yep, right. That will not work if the observation model not created yet. For my projects i`m using just random generated names.